# Where are the Page Manager "Caching options"?

Tags: caching, panels

In D7 I'm using Ctools, Panels (3), Views, Page Manager etc., but in Page Manager when gear-icon-clicking the content panes I don't find any "Caching options" as I have seen described. What reasons can there be for this. 
It's probably something really simple, I just can't find it...

Comment: Around 7:20-7:50 you can see how to get to the caching options for a panel pane
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jRoMgZTg1GE&t=7m20s
In this video the guy is removing the pane, but right above that is the selection for caching.

Comment: Are you sure you are clicking on a content type, and not a region? Regions have the same gear icon, but can't have caching options.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Panel Cache]

[image: Pane Cache]

Although the language is german in this screenshot, location of the menu/options should be the same.